# Controllable system?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, control-theory, classical-mechanics

So I have my equation of motion for an inverted pendulum on a cart: (linearised about the upright position and X denoting the position of the cart):

$$ \ddot{\theta}-\theta = \ddot{X} $$

Rather than dealing with a 4x4 system I’d like to set $\ddot{X} = a \theta +b \dot{\theta}$ but now I’m struggling to write my system in the form:

$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$$

as I can’t determine what my control Bu is now that I’m not applying a direct force to the cart?

Answer (score 0):

You are only using one half of the [equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum#Lagrange's_Equations). The other half contains an external force, which will be your input $u$.